# Using span, other texts are going in the next line

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have texts in two spans, but they are not beside each other. (The last text is below the previous text, but it should be beside the previous.)

Here is the code from where the texts are printed:

```
var display_options_1 = `

         <td><span id="A${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[0]}</span><span>${question.option_text[0]}</span></td>
         <td><span id="B${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[1]}</span><span>${question.option_text[1]}</span></td>`;

var display_options_2 = `

         <td><span id="C${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[2]}</span><span>${question.option_text[2]}</span></td>
         <td><span id="D${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[3]}</span><span>${question.option_text[3]}</td>`;
```

Here is the [**full code**](http://jsbin.com/legipukuvu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) with a working [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/qabuduqazo/)!

> It was easier to solve the problem with one `<span>`,
>
> ```
> <span id="C${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[ ]}
> ```
>
> ${question.option_text[ ]}
>
> , but I need only **`${question.options[]}`** to be selected not
>   `${question.option_text[ ]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines

```
<td><span id="A${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[0]}</span><span>${question.option_text[0]}
<td><span id="B${i}" class="${question.questionId}" onclick="onSelect(event)">${question.options[1]}</span><span>${question.option_text[1]}
```

to these

```
<td><span onclick="onSelect(event)" class="${question.questionId}" ><span id="A${i}" >${question.options[0]}</span><span>${question.option_text[0]}</span></span>
<td><span onclick="onSelect(event)" class="${question.questionId}"><span id="B${i}"  >${question.options[1]}</span><span>${question.option_text[1]}</span></span>
```

Remove `width: 90%` on `.question1`

Add the locked/correct/incorrect classes on the the first child of the selection like

```
selection.firstElementChild.setAttribute('class', 'locked');
```

Also change the line where correct answer is checked

```
if (currentQuestion.answer === e.currentTarget.firstElementChild.innerText) {
```

```js
var x;

var questions = [{
  questionId: "question1",
  answerId: "C",
  question: "1) जो भवनों में रहते हैं, वे है ?(C186506)",
  options: ["A)", "B)", "C)", "D)"],
  option_text: ["ज्योतिष्क ", "वैमानिक", "भवनपति ", "व्यंतर"],
  answer: "C)",
  locked: false
}];

var table = document.getElementById("test");
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.colSpan = 2;
var i = 0;


function generateQuestion(question) {
  // noinspection JSAnnotator
  i += 1;
  var newQuestion = `
        
            <td colspan="2"><div class="question1" style="justify-content: center; width: 100%;">${question.question}`;
  var display_options_1 = `
 
            <td><span onclick="onSelect(event)" class="${question.questionId}" ><span id="A${i}" >${question.options[0]}</span><span>${question.option_text[0]}</span></span>
            <td><span onclick="onSelect(event)" class="${question.questionId}"><span id="B${i}"  >${question.options[1]}</span><span>${question.option_text[1]}</span></span>
  `;
  var display_options_2 = `
 
            <td><span onclick="onSelect(event)" class="${question.questionId}" ><span id="C${i}" >${question.options[2]}</span><span>${question.option_text[2]}</span></span>
            <td><span   onclick="onSelect(event)" class="${question.questionId}"><span id="D${i}">${question.options[3]}</span><span>${question.option_text[3]}</span></span>
  `;
  var row2 = table.insertRow(1);
  row2.innerHTML = newQuestion;

  var row3 = table.insertRow(2);
  setTimeout(() => {
    row3.innerHTML = display_options_1;
  }, 2000);
  var row4 = table.insertRow(3);
  setTimeout(function() {
    row4.innerHTML = display_options_2;
  }, 2000);

  var points_display = "1";
  var points_set = "237512";
  var t_points = "237513";
  var distance = "10";
}

function onSelect(e) {
  var selection = e.currentTarget;
  var questionId = e.currentTarget.className;
  var currentQuestion = questions.find(function(q) {
    return q.questionId == questionId;
  });



  if (currentQuestion.locked) {
    alert("Question already answered");
  } else if (currentQuestion.answer === e.currentTarget.firstElementChild.innerText) {
    clearInterval(x);

    //table.deleteRow(0);
    //document.getElementById("timer").setAttribute('class', 'hidden_timer');
    selection.firstElementChild.setAttribute('class', 'locked');
    alert("Correct!!!");
    currentQuestion.locked = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      selection.setAttribute('class', 'correct');
    }, 2000);

  } else {
    alert("Incorrect...");
    clearInterval(x);
    //table.deleteRow(0);
    //document.getElementById("timer").setAttribute('class', 'hidden_timer');
    selection.firstElementChild.setAttribute('class', 'locked');
    currentQuestion.locked = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      selection.firstElementChild.setAttribute('class', 'incorrect');
      console.log(document.getElementById(currentQuestion.answerId + i));
      document.getElementById(currentQuestion.answerId + i).setAttribute('class', 'correct');
    }, 2000);
  }
  //generateQuestion(questions[i]);
}

function startTest() {
  generateQuestion(questions[i]);
}
```

```css
.correct {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.correct::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid green;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.correct::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid green;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.lifeline {
  background-color: pink;
  color: white;
}

.incorrect {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.incorrect::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid red;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.incorrect::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.locked {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  color: white;
}

.locked::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid yellow;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.locked::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid yellow;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.timeout {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}

.hidden_timer {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  visibility: visible !important
}

.timeout {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
}

.timeout::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid orange;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.timeout::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid orange;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.question1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.question1::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 20px solid blue;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.question1::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 20px solid blue;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}

.table_cstm {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 15;
  /* Apply cell spacing */
  table-layout: fixed
}

td:last-child div {
  margin-left: auto;
}


/* Play header starts */

.button_cstm_quit {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.button_cstm_quit:hover {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.button_cstm_ll {
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.button_cstm_ll:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.button_cst_pnts {
  background-color: orange;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.button_cst_pnt:hover {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.button_cstm_nxt {
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.button_cstm_nxt:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.button_cstm_time {
  background-color: #FF8C00;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.button_cstm_time:hover {
  color: #FF8C00;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid #FF8C00;
}

#container_cstm {
  width: 100%;
}

#left_cstm {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

#right_cstm {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
}

#center_cstm {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}

#play_head {
  display: flex;
  /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* default value; can be omitted */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  /* default value; can be omitted */
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* switched from default (flex-start, see below) */
}

.red_cross:before,
.red_cross:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  width: 5px;
  background: #ff0000;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.red_cross:before {
  transform: skew(30deg);
}

.red_cross:after {
  transform: skew(-30deg);
}

.disp_none {
  display: none;
}


/* Play header ends */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body onload="startTest()">


  <div class="container">
    <table id="test" class="table table-responsive table_cstm" cellspacing="100">

    </table>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this what you want ?

Comment: Please read the banner content in the question once again carefully, thanks for the interest!

Comment: Updated the answer, please check now.

Comment: Click on the `option C` it will alert `incorrect` though it is the correct answer!

Comment: there is some logical bug in your code. try looking for it. i will do too when i m back at my seat. not on my pc right now.

Comment: Updated the answer, check now

Comment: I think there's no need of adding `firstElementChld` at `selection.firstElementChild.setAttribute('class', 'locked');`. Then it is working as expected. After removing this try the script twice (first-time select right option, then second-time wrong option), you will get the difference...

Comment: M glad you figured it out :) The person who writes the code is always faster in debugging it :)

Comment: Yes, you are right as he/she knows the expectation clearly... There is a small bug when the user chooses the wrong option...(The CSS effect)

Answer (score 0):

`class="${question.questionId}"` this class is assigning `display: flex` which is making the next `span` go next line. 
Solution:
Add another `div` which contains both `spans` and assign `class="${question.questionId}"`

PS: I tried in that demo, but it's not allowing me to run and check my answer correctness.

Answer (score 0):

**span** is an inline element. You must have changed its display property somewhere in CSS code. Just try adding

`display: inline-block;`

to your span element.